# Cannot getting the ObjectId from node js restful api mongoose using jquery ajax put method

Tags: node.js

this the jquery ajax code
this the node js RESTful API

this is button from the front-end

Comment: What is `this.getId()`? You can use `this.id`

Comment: I use that last time but the objectid is undefined :-(

Comment: var _id = this.id;
            alert("Update");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/' + _id,
                //data: this.model.exportJSON(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
                    console.log('XHR ERROR ' + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                }
            });